# How do i loop an array inside a class - Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'd like to loop an array called data, inside another array filled with 'champions' what is the correct syntax for this? i can happily loop all of the champions inside of my IChampion, but i can't seem to loop the IChampionData[]

IChampion.ts

```
import { IChampionData } from "./champion-data";

export interface IChampion {
   type: string;
   format: string;
   version: string;
   data: IChampionData[];
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='table-responsive'>
<table class='table table-striped'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Champion Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let champion of champion">
            <td>{{champion1.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The data is what i want to loop, i have a variable inside IChampionData called name and i'm not sure how to get the variable.

Here's an example of the JSON

```
  "data": {
        "Aatrox": {
            "version": "6.24.1",
            "id": "Aatrox",
            "key": "266",
            "name": "Aatrox",
            "title": "the Darkin Blade",
            "blurb": "Aatrox is a legendary warrior, one of only five that remain of an ancient race known as the Darkin. He wields his massive blade with grace and poise, slicing through legions in a style that is hypnotic to behold. With each foe felled, Aatrox's ...",
            "info": {
                "attack": 8,
                "defense": 4,
                "magic": 3,
                "difficulty": 4
            },
            "image": {
                "full": "Aatrox.png",
                "sprite": "champion0.png",
                "group": "champion",
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "w": 48,
                "h": 48
            },
            "tags": [
                "Fighter",
                "Tank"
            ],
            "partype": "BloodWell",
            "stats": {
                "hp": 537.8,
                "hpperlevel": 85.0,
                "mp": 105.6,
                "mpperlevel": 45.0,
                "movespeed": 345.0,
                "armor": 24.384,
                "armorperlevel": 3.8,
                "spellblock": 32.1,
                "spellblockperlevel": 1.25,
                "attackrange": 150.0,
                "hpregen": 6.59,
                "hpregenperlevel": 0.5,
                "mpregen": 0.0,
                "mpregenperlevel": 0.0,
                "crit": 0.0,
                "critperlevel": 0.0,
                "attackdamage": 60.376,
                "attackdamageperlevel": 3.2,
                "attackspeedoffset": -0.04,
                "attackspeedperlevel": 3.0
            }
        }
```

and here is my attempt at the Model

```
import { IChampionStats } from './champion-stats';
import { IChampionImage } from './champion-image';
import { IChampionInfo } from './champion-info';

export interface IChampionData {
   version: string;
   id: string;
   key: string;
   name: string;
   title: string;
   blurb: string;
   info: IChampionInfo[];
   image: IChampionImage[];
   tags: string[];
   partype: string;
   stats: IChampionStats[];
 }
```

Comment: What is the actual JSON, since that JSON seems to be just a snippet of inner JSON, since it doesn't match all your interfaces?

Comment: This is the full json file: https://pastebin.com/ncBhC2tH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now actually knowing how your code looks like... it's actually an array with one object that you are receiving, and object with objects in it.

```ts
[{
 "version": "6.24.1",
 "data": {
   "Aatrox": {
     "version": "6.24.1",
     "id": "Aatrox",
     "key": "266",
     "name": "Aatrox",
     "info": {
       "attack": 8,
        ...
     }
     ...
   },
   ...
}]
```

So what you are trying to do, loop objects, that cannot be looped with `*ngFor`. So you have problems with your interfaces first of all. You have marked arrays on most places, where the data is actually objects. So your interfaces should look like this:

```ts
export interface IChampion {
   type: string;
   format: string;
   version: string;
   data: IChampionData; // this is an object!
}

export interface IChampionData {
   version: string;
   id: string;
   key: string;
   name: string;
   title: string;
   blurb: string;
   info: IChampionInfo; // this is an object!
   image: IChampionImage; // this is an object!
   tags: string[]; // this is actually an array
   partype: string;
   stats: IChampionStats; // this is an object!
}
```

You could use a custom pipe to iterate each object in template (which is the name of the champion), or then manipulate the data you are receiving and transform it as such that you can iterate it. I'd do the latter... this way:

First in your mapping, I would just get the object inside the array, so:

```ts
.map(res => res.json()[0]) // get the first and only object
```

Then subscribe:

```ts
.subscribe(data => {
  // push the data from outermost data and add array for your champions
  this.championGroup = {type: data.type, format: data.format version:data.version,data:[]}
  // get the object keys (champion names)
  let keyArr: any[] = Object.keys(data.data)
  // for each object key, push its content to array
  keyArr.forEach((key: any) => {
     this.championGroup.data.push(data.data[key]);
  });
});
```

Then you can iterate your data fine:

```html
<table class='table table-striped'>
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Champion Name</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let champion of championGroup?.data">
       <td>{{champion.name}}</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Notice the **[safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator)**, which safeguards `null` and `undefined` property paths.

Finally a **[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/GJlkGZdjdvZaRBkWqkaZ?p=preview)** to demonstrate this with part of your code.

Please then notice for the nested objects, that you do not try and iterate them. So for example you can in your template show `attack` inside `info` with 
`{{champion?.info?.attack}}`.

Comment: https://medium.com/@jsayol/having-fun-with-angular-extending-ngfor-to-support-for-in-f30c724967ed

Comment: Whoa yurzui. Thanks a lot again my hero! I've totally missed this one as well. I have a slight memory of seeing this used somewhere, but I guess I haven't paid attention (nothing new there, hah). Feel ashamed of my answer now. There is always a better way than my way, haha. Don't understand the couple of upvotes for this now...

Answer (score 1):

```
<span *ngFor="let x of champion.data">{{ x.name }}</span>
```

`span` or whatever tag you need

Answer (score 1):

Just use **`champion.data`**,

```
 <tr *ngFor="let champion of champion.data">
            <td>{{champion.name}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: It's not populating my table for some reason, not throwing errors, and the json is printing out just fine :S

Comment: check the syntax

Comment: try with champion.data instead of champions.data

Comment: it's not champion, it's champions, that was a mistype on my half, apologies for that.

Comment: according to the data you posted its not an array

Comment: What do you mean, it works fine for the first elements such as 'version' but trying to get into the IChampionData[] is not working, i have no idea why.